# What is the best method to append text to TextBox element in Universal Windows Apps

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

In my Universal Windows App i want to log some events and writing them in a TextBox Element. But i couldn't find a method like named "appendText". And below method makes flickering on screen

```
txtbox.Text += log;
```

What is the best method to appendText for TextBox or TextBlock or RichTextEdit elements?

Comment: I've found that a better choice is to use an `ItemsControl` or a `ListBox` as its more log oriented. It won't flicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to display some logging information, it might be read only information so using a TextBlock is already an optimization. Then, depending on your needs, a multi-item control such as a ListBox, ListView or GridView might be even better for logs.
If you have more than hundreds of lines, think about using virtualization.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt574120.aspx